# ld failed to link

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, ld

Dear All,
Here is my command to link libraries and generate an exe:

```
ld -o readgfile  readg_x.o MedLib_x.o cdrsort.o mtcprc.o encoder.o mtcbuil.o dbtprc.o dbtbuil.o  DFMLIB_x.o Dyn_SQL_x.o /home/med/src/api/libnapi.a  /home/med/src/api/libtabs.a $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so
```

But when I run the command it failed to locate function used in readg_x.o from file archived in libtabs.a. Here are error like :

```
readg_x.o: In function `main':
/home/med/src/readg/readg_x.c:565: undefined reference to `options'
/home/med/src/readg/readg_x.c:570: undefined reference to `oraconnect'
/home/med/src/readg/readg_x.c:591: undefined reference to `oracommit'
```

Comment: That's not lds fault. Something is wrong with your code. Maybe you're using a variable/function that is exported in a header but not actually implemented.

Comment: Thanks Haldan for your reply. Well all these functions are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The error means the library `libtabs.a` doesn't contain what you think. You can use tools like `objdump` to list all symbols defined in a library to make sure what you expect is what really is.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I have checked with nm command these symbols are defined in the libtabs.a

Comment: Did you define them in a header file so that the type is known in `readg_x.c`? Is the type the same in `readg_x.c` and in the C source file which you compiled into `libtabs.a`? What happens if you write a small C file which contains, say, `options` and add that to the `ld` command?

Comment: I have check with a small c program, it is compiled and executed :(

Comment: So that means there must be a difference between your small C test and your full code. Ask the compiler to produce assembler for you. Now search the assembler code for "oraconnect" and look if there is a difference.

Comment: This is from small program: .LCFI1:
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    hello
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    oraconnect

This is from actual program. Still errors 
.L13:
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    oraconnect
        testl   %eax, %eax
        je      .L14

Comment: Is that the only place where "oraconnect" is mentioned? Also try to run `ld` with `--verbose`.

Comment: What does `--verbose` say about this symbol?

Comment: happy news that I able to compile by giving local path. But when I tried to run exe, it gives following error : ./readgfile: /lib/ld64.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Ah!!! You're mixing 32bit and 64bit libraries! That doesn't work. Make sure all libraries use the same pointer width.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You are trying to build an executable with `ld`. Once you manage to actually link it, the resulting executable will crash at startup, because you are not properly linking in the C startup (`crt0.o`). On UNIX/Linux, one should *never* use `ld` to link anything (with the rare exception of linking OS kernel or a bootloader). You should *always* use compiler driver instead, like this: `gcc -o readgfile readg_x.o MedLib_x.o ...`
2. Even though you have claimed that `oraconnect` etc. are defined in `libtabs.a`, they are not (or at least they are not defined as global symbols). Without output from `readelf -s libtabs.a | grep oraconnect`, it is hard to tell *exactly* what's happening, but your assertion that the symbols are defined in that library is definitely false.

Comment: Dear ER,Thank you for your reply.Here is the output of the command  you told readelf -s libtabs.a | grep oraconnect
    77: 0000000000000647   860 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 oraconnect
    87: 00000000000009fc   634 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 oraconnect_ret      I am compiling with -o but it was also giving same error